# Get specific character from a string using Typescript

Tags: javascript

I have this string **4-1111**

How to extract the **4** only?. I mean any character/s before the ( **-** ).

Comment: have you tried using a [tag:regex]?

Comment: Could you clarify why did you tag the question with TypeScript - do you want to create a type to which only strings starting with digits before a dash are assignable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split` following should work :-

```js
let string = "44234-1111"
console.log(string.split('-')[0]);
```

`.split` returns `['44234','1111']` and you can select the index 0 entry.

Answer (score 1):

Split would work

```js
'4-1111'.split('-')[0];
```